# Swift - WebView doesn't detect swipes when loading

Tags: ios, swift, url, webview, swipe

Before the URL is finished loading, my swipes are not detected, after swipes are detected. Any idea how to detect swipes while URL is loading?

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out, we just need to add these 2 lines:

```
webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(rightSwipeGesture)
webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(leftSwipeGesture)
```

Full example:

```
var rightSwipeGesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipeGesture))
var leftSwipeGesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipeGesture))
rightSwipeGesture.direction = .Right
leftSwipeGesture.direction = .Left
self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeGesture)
self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeGesture)
webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(rightSwipeGesture)
webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(leftSwipeGesture)
```